# Can I use INDIRECT within SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

This is my second question and so far you all have been very helpful!

I currently have this formula in place and it works great:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((H2:H415=R63)*(K2:K415=R63))
```

Column H = 5 unique text

Column K = The same 5 unique text.

I added the 5 unique text into R63:R67

Right now I am counting to see how many times R63 shows up in H2:H415 AND K2:K415.

The issue I'm having is the H415 and K415 are going to be forever increment in size. IE: 415, 416, 417, 418 etc.

In the past I have used `INDIRECT` as a method for 415 being in an updated/variable cell.

Is there a way I can have something similar within `SUMPRODUCT`?

Please note that Column H and K may be BLANK cells.

Thank you in advanced for the tips, suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still take the whole column...

```
=SUMPRODUCT((H:H=R63)*(K:K=R63))
```

It will take some time to evaluate but if you want to use `INDIRECT`, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("H2:H"&D2)=R63)*(INDIRECT("K2:K"&D2)=R63))
```

assuming that the last column number is stored in cell D2 like in your previous question. You'll have to update cell D2 constantly, however.

Comment: Awesome. You guys are great. Thanks Jerry.

=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("H2:H"&D2)=R63)*(INDIRECT("K2:K"&D2)=R63))

The above comes back with a #REF! 

However,

=SUMPRODUCT((H:H=R63)*(K:K=R63))

Works perfectly. This will help a lot. I don't mind updating Cell D2. But if there's another way to Automate, that would be helpful too, but not required. 

Thanks again for everyones contribution!

Comment: @user2762319 If you have 415 (or a value above 1) in D2, it shouldn't be returning the error. Otherwise, the first formula is as simple and less likely to need manual updates as can be.

Comment: You're right, I didn't have the correct value in D2. This works perfectly also. Both will do exactly what I need. I am also using an array on a separate column A to automate my "D2" cell. The array I'm using is:

=MIN(IF(A1:A99999="",ROW(A1:A99999)-ROW(A1)+1))-1

Now I can just add in my rows and my D2 will update, thus updating my formulas.

You guys have been great. I will be coming back here and letting more people know of the amazing help. Regards -Eric

Comment: @user2762319 You can use `COUNTA(A1:A99999)-1` to get that number. But BarryHoudini (answer below) has a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `COUNTIFS`? More efficient than `SUMPRODUCT`, i.e

`=COUNTIFS(H:H,R63,K:K,R63)`

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of that. This too does exactly as needed. I have just fallen victim to overcomplicating things. All 3 answers have done exactly what I needed and I realize now there's no 1 way to skin a cat. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing "below" the 415, change it to something large enough to encompass further expansion, yet small enough to not slow down worksheet calculation.  Something like:

**=SUMPRODUCT((H2:H9999=R63)*(K2:K9999=R63))**

Comment: This works too, Gary's Student. I'm using both answers to also help with an Array with the same large range. This will work perfectly as I am constantly updating my spreadsheet and enjoy looking at the graphs over time. Thank you.

Comment: @user2762319 I like Barry's method the best.